# ASP.NET weird behaviour on render

Tags: asp.net

We are developing a web application and are having problems with one particular page. Intermittently, the page fails to render. The HTML returned by the server is truncated, always at the same point. It's quite a big complex page with lots of MS Ajax and a telerik treeview control.

We usually find that if we navigate away from the page whilst it's hung, we get an unhandled exception (I understand why this occurs), and then we go back to the page, it loads fine.

We've dropped lots of logging into the page code behind file. It completes the Page_Load event code. We've overriden the OnRender event and execution enters this event handler, but when things go awry, it hangs there.

Another thing we've noticed - it works finr when we run it on localhost - the error only manifests itself on a production server.

Many thanks for any help - we've spent the day pulling our hair out

Cheers

Tony
P.S. ASP.NET 3.5

Comment: We could guess randomly for a long time.  Would really help if you post the code.

Comment: How much hair do you pull out in a day, and will you get an answer before you're all bald? If you post more code you'll likely keep more hair.

Comment: JDK - wow - you've invented a cure for baldness. Note to self: reverse hair loss by posting lots of code on Stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How big is the resulting page (html size)?  And how long does it take to generate the page?

Just wondering if it's either too large or takes too long.

Check the httpRuntime element, executionTimeout and maxRequestLength properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

-Krip

Comment: Thanks. The page can take some time to generate, but it's divided into a number of panels. When the page is OK, the first panel renders in perhaps 500mS, most of which is transport delay. When the page bombs, no panels render at all

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the culprit. For some reason, somebody had added a Response.Buffer=false directive to the page. Removing it seems to have cured the problem

thanks to all who replied